# How to play a segment of a movie in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, time, movie

I have a video, and I want to display the video at a specific time time and stop it at a specific time. I am using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at the [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and the [`initialPlaybackTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/initialPlaybackTime) and [`endPlaybackTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/endPlaybackTime) properties.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
player.initialPlaybackTime = 5; // beginning time in seconds
player.endPlaybackTime = 15; // end time for playback in seconds
```